# how to execute multiple php queries with odbc_exec

Tags: php, mysql, odbc, pervasive-sql

I am inserting multiple records into mysql with the codes below. However, after inserting into mysql, I need to insert same into pervasive sql for use by pastel. I use odbc_exec  which works well if record to be inserted is jus one. I need help pls.

```
$query .= '
   INSERT INTO supplier_invoice
        (inv_number, SupplCode, Item_No, product_name, 
         qty, unitPrice, subtotal, inv_dt, created_by) 
   VALUES("'.$inv_No.'", "'.$supp_code.'", "'.$itNo.'", "'.$itName.'", 
          "'.$qqty.'", "'.$cost.'", "'.$ttotal.'", "'.$inv_dt.'", 
          "'.$submitted_by.'"); 
   ';
```

Comment: I assume by the use of **`$query .=`** you create more than one insert in the `$query` variable and then try and execute those queries all in one go?

Comment: It might have been helpful if you showed us the database access code as well as a simple loading of a string variable

Comment: Which by the way is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok I will

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use other way to consider query:

At start:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO supplier_invoice
        (inv_number, SupplCode, Item_No, product_name, 
         qty, unitPrice, subtotal, inv_dt, created_by) 
   VALUES ';
$first_query = true;
```

In the loop:

```
if ($first_query) {
    $first_query = false;
} else {
    $quetry .= ',';
}
$query .= '("'.$inv_No.'", "'.$supp_code.'", "'.$itNo.'", "'.$itName.'", 
      "'.$qqty.'", "'.$cost.'", "'.$ttotal.'", "'.$inv_dt.'", 
      "'.$submitted_by.'")';
```